# How do I automatically update a Google spreadsheet when a Google calendar is changed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a script on a Google spreadsheet that reads a Google calendar and populates its cells.

How can I make it so that the spreadsheet is automatically updated when I make a change on the calendar instead of me manually having to open the spreadsheet and run the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, there is no event that Google Apps Script can catch when something is changed in a calendar.

What I do is setting a timer trigger that checks data in sheet against calendar and do something when a change is detected.

I do so every 30' and check only on a few coming weeks because it is sufficient for my use case but if you need an extended time period to be checked very often then beware the quota limits !(max processing time = 1h/day)